# Generate different images by languages in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I want to generate different images depending on the languages with TypoScript.

```
<img src="/specilized-nl.png" alt="logo">            
<img src="/specilized-en.png" alt="logo">      
<img src="/specilized-de.png" alt="logo">
```

So depending on the selected languages the correct image is shown by using a different image name. How could this be done?

Comment: From where do you generate the image link? TypoScript, Fluid, something entirely differen?

Comment: I want to generate the link from typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [conditions](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html) on language parameter (most probably `L`)...

```
lib.myImage = <img src="/specilized-nl.png" alt="logo">

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
  lib.myImage = <img src="/specilized-en.png" alt="logo">
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
  lib.myImage = <img src="/specilized-de.png" alt="logo">
[global]
```

Of course I assume in that sample, the NL is default, EN has uid 1, and DE has uid 2, fix it to reflect your real situation.